# Automapper - Map several tables to one ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I have a StudentClassViewModel that looks kind of like this:

```
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }

    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public string ClassName{ get; set; }
    public string ClassSubject { get; set; }
```

The first 4 properties are from the Student Table, and last 3 are from the CLass Table.  I am mapping with AutoMapper and I am hoping to find out how to map from the ViewModel to both tables, the theory being that the VM returns the data from the View to the Controller, where I want to map from the VM to the 2 separate tables for saving.

I am thinking it should be in the 'CreateMap' config, something like:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<StudentClassViewModel, Student>()
            .ForMember(x => x.ClassId, y => y.Some how map to the Class table)
            .ForMember(x => x.ClassName, y => y.Some how map to the Class table)
            .ForMember(x => x.ClassSubject, y => y.Some how map to the Class table));
```

It is also possible I have completely missed the point of auto mapping, either way, let me know.

Comment: What's the relationship between student and class. Looks like many to many, so how do you decide which class is for the view model?

Comment: Yes it is many to many, so I am having to reconstruct it a bit.  Gruff Bunny's answer has given me what I need to proceed.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have control over the destination objects then you could add a Class property to the Student class and let AutoMapper handle the mapping for you:

```
public class StudentClassViewModel
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }

    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
    public string ClassSubject { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }

    public Class Class { get; set; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<StudentClassViewModel, Student>();

var student = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<StudentClassViewModel>(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

If those two table are complete separate, then there is no easy way.
However if there is a relation between Student and Class, like a Student attends a Class:

```
public class Class
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Subject {get; set;}
}

public class Student
{
    public string FullName {get; set;}
    public Class Class {get; set;}
}
```

You can just map like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<StudentClassViewModel, Student>()
    .ForMember(x => x.ClassId, y => y.Student.Class.Id)
    .ForMember(x => x.ClassName, y => y.Student.Class.Name)
    .ForMember(x => x.ClassSubject, y => y.Student.Class.Subject));
```